# Which subject shall we chose for the upcomming blog-post?

Tags: discussion, community-blog

Since the previous blog-posts were about Ramadan and Da'wah, this upcoming blog-post shall be about this site.  There are a number of topics the blog-post could be about our site, it could be about Issues this site is facing, or it can be about a certain issue, or it can be something else.  So with the subject of the blog-post in mind (The subject: About the site) this discussion shall be about gathering suggestions on what topic should be written, whether it is about some issue we are facing or not, and have the suggestions voted on.